# SQL Procedure error

Tags: sql, postgresql

Changed into a procedure, getting a syntax error at 'PROCEDURE' any ideas?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE performance_Report
 @startDate DATE,
 @endDate DATE
AS
    SELECT Salesrep.Name, SUM(OrderLine.Quantity) AS Total_Sold, SUM(OrderLine.UnitSellingPrice * Orderline.Quantity) AS Total_Value
    FROM SalesRep, OrderLine, ShopOrder
    WHERE ShopOrder.SalesRepID = SalesRep.SalesRepID
    AND OrderLine.ShopOrderID = ShopOrder.ShopOrderID
    AND ShopOrder.OrderDate BETWEEN @startDate AND endDate
    GROUP BY SalesRep.SalesRepID, SalesRep.Name
    ORDER BY Total_Value DESC;
```

Comment: What database is this? If it is SQL Server, you probably need to use @startDate DATETIME instead of @startDate DATE.

Comment: pgAdmin, even with no input parameters the syntax error is still there.

Comment: This syntax has nothing to do with PostgreSQL, even the language you want to use for the procedure is missing. Open the manual and start learning how to write a stored procedure (function that is) in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL doesn't have "CREATE PROCEDURE". It is [reported](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/15-Stored-Procedures-in-PostgreSQL.html) that most of what you might need stored procedures for in other databases can be done in PostgreSQL with [CREATE FUNCTION](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html).

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that. You want your view to result in an aggregation by SalesRep.Name. What you want to do is filtering those SUMs. You have two options:

1. Create a Stored Procedure instead of a View. That way you can have the Start date and End date as input parameters for the filtering.
2. Do not create a DB structure at all, just use the query and have you source code populate the parameters.

**EDIT**

So, you changed the question and now you want to create a stored procedure in PostgreSql. You might want to take a look at this: [A Basic Introduction to Postgres Stored Procedures](http://www.eioba.com/a/1ign/a-basic-introduction-to-postgres-stored-procedures). Take your time to read it, the knowledge acquired in the process will surely be helpful. And, on your way through it, you might reevaluate and think you don't really need that kind of functionality for a straightforward query such as this one. Good luck.

Comment: I edited the answer to direct you into taking a look on how to create a Stored Procedure in Postgresql. Hope it helps.

Comment: @user195257 Were you able to do it? Let us know

Answer (score 0):

From outside of the view definition you don't have access to the underlying tables.

Comment: Ahhhh of course.. Is there anyway of using views for this query?

Comment: You can try adding `OrderDate` to the view's `SELECT`. But it will change the resultset - you will also need to group by `OrderDate` which may be not what you want... Also, it will degrade performance compared to normal `WHERE`

Comment: I tried this before but it doesnt give me the desired result as you say, thankyou anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didn't mean to use [`CREATE FUNCTION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html):

```
CREATE FUNCTION performance_Report(date, date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `AND ShopOrder.OrderDate BETWEEN @startDate AND endDate` shouldn't that be `AND ShopOrder.OrderDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate`?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE performance_Report
 @startDate DATE,
 @endDate DATE
AS
    SELECT Salesrep.Name, SUM(OrderLine.Quantity) AS Total_Sold, SUM(OrderLine.UnitSellingPrice * Orderline.Quantity) AS Total_Value
    FROM SalesRep, OrderLine, ShopOrder
    WHERE ShopOrder.SalesRepID = SalesRep.SalesRepID
    AND OrderLine.ShopOrderID = ShopOrder.ShopOrderID
    AND ShopOrder.OrderDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
    GROUP BY SalesRep.SalesRepID, SalesRep.Name
    ORDER BY Total_Value DESC;
```

Otherwise does this query work if you remove that line entirely without being a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE PROCEDURE` was introduced to PostgreSQL in version 11, so if you are using an earlier version you will get `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "PROCEDURE"`