# Procedures not working in pgAdmin

Tags: sql, postgresql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Procedure error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559222/sql-procedure-error)

Hello, i cant get my procedures working in pgAdmin, not even a simple one like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_Proc
AS
    SELECT * FROM Category;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "PROCEDURE"
LINE 1: CREATE PROCEDURE test_Proc
```

Any ideas why this is happening?